# Symfony Apache configuration when app_dev is in a subdirectory

Tags: php, symfony

I am running a Symfony 3 app on my local wondows machine. It's served with a XAMPP server. The app runs fine when i visite my local URL. The problems is that I can't seem to be able to run it in the dev envirement.

The Symfony app folder structure is diffrent then what I am used to. The app_dev.php is located in the intranet folder.

[image]

This is the intranet folder

[image]

My current apache config file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName quebecenreseau.ca
    ServerAlias www.quebecenreseau.ca

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "crt/quebecenreseau.ca/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "crt/quebecenreseau.ca/server.key"

    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\quebecenreseau
    <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\quebecenreseau>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/project>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog C:\xampp\apache\logs\project_error.log
    CustomLog C:\xampp\apache\logs\project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I am unsure how to configure the VirtualHost block in order to get the dev envirement working on both, the root directory as well as the intranet directory that serves as the admin of the website.

If I change the DocumentRoot line like so:

```
DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\quebecenreseau\intranet\app_dev.php
```

My app CSS files are not loaded and my intranet is served at the root level. How can I configure my local envirement to load app_dev.php? Also, my prod envirement is on a centos server so I really don't wana mess with the prod envirement.

In case you wander whats inside the index.php file at the root level here it is:

```
<?php

/**
 * Start session
 */

session_start();

/**
 * Load configuration and router
 */

require 'classes/Router.php';
require 'classes/Database.php';
require 'classes/Main.php';

/**
 * Load helpers
 */

require 'helpers/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'helpers/GUMP.php';
require 'helpers/MailChimp.php';


/**
 * Load models
 */

require 'models/Article.php';
require 'models/Formation.php';
require 'models/SAE.php';


/**
 * Load routes
 */

require 'router.php';


/**
 * Match requests
 */

$match = $router->match();

if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    // call function related to matched route
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
} else {
    // no route was matched
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `C:\xampp\htdocs\quebecenreseau` to `C:\xampp\htdocs\quebecenreseau\intranet\web`. if I remember well, the document root must point to the folder where app.php and app_dev.php are located.

UPDATE:

Ok. It is a bit more clear now. You are not running a pure Symfony project in the prod. Someone took some basic classes from Symfony and used to route requests and handle DB connections.

Right now you have actually two projects. A plain PHP project in the main folder and a Symfony project in the intranet folder.

So let's start working on it. First, you have to know that for a Symfony project to work properly as the main application, the root folder must be the "web" folder.

So:

1. Create a new Symfony project in the quebecenreseau folder.
2. Move the existing assets to the new asset folder
3. Check if the existing controllers need some tweaking to show the assets.

From what I see from the structure, you will need to do minimal changes to make it work.

Comment: Take a closser look to the screenshots. The app folder and the app_dev are located in the \quebecenreseau\intranet folder. Thats the whole problem. If I point to \quebecenreseau the app works in "prod" mode ans if I point to \quebecenreseau\intranet the whole app breaks and I can't access the frontend of the website.

Comment: I see what you mean. But I am not sure the `quebecenreseau` folder is looking at the prod environment. I don't see a file named `app.php` in there. It is probably looking at the `index.php` file. Also, from the vhost file you have, I come at the conclusion that you are using the index.php file there.

Comment: Check what the index.php contains. Probably someone copy-pasted the code from app.php and didn't make the appropriate changes.

Comment: I added the content of index.php in my main question. Does not seem to be the same thing.

Comment: I agree. It seems it just loads some classes for routing and handling DB connections.

Comment: I don't think your prod environment is actually a full-blown symfony project. Someone just added some basic classes from Symfony. Usually the difference between prod and dev environment is that the dev environment loads a couple more bundles for debugging and profiling.

Comment: Thx guys this explains it. Since this was my first time working on symfony i had no clue what it normaly looks like. I create a new symfony project from scratch and had no problem gething debug to work. Looks like this project is a lot diffrent and the old programmers kind of messed up how it should normaly work. I never got the debug to work but managed to do all the needed changes. I am gona play a little with symfony and get use to the framework in case i get more jobs like this one.