# Symfony 3.4 - Sending out an email (Call to a member function get() on null (500 Internal Server Error))

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on the last part of my reset password system. All I need is for Symfony to send the URL that contain the token by email. When I execute the controller I get the following message:

> Call to a member function get() on null (500 Internal Server Error)

If I remove the "extends Controller" I get this error

[image]

[image]

What I don't get is that I copied the code from an other controller in the same project that sends email with out any problems.

My controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event;

use CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEvent;
use AppBundle\AppBundle;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\ImportForm;
use AppBundle\Form\UserRegistrationForm;
use AppBundle\Form\UserEditForm;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

class ForgotPasswordEventListener extends Controller
{
    
    private $templating;
    private $manager;
    
    public function __construct($templating, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->manager=$manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param ForgotPasswordEvent $event
     */
    public function onCreateToken(ForgotPasswordEvent $event)
    {
        $passwordToken = $event->getPasswordToken();
        $user = $passwordToken->getUser();
        
            $message = $this->templating->render(
                '_Emails/change-password.html.twig',
                [
                    'name' => $user->getName(),
                    'tokenLink' => "https://www.quebecenreseau.ca/intranet/password-change/".$user->getId()."/".$passwordToken->getToken()
                ]
            );

            $this->get('app.mailer')->send([
                'from' => 'noreply@quebecenreseau.ca',
                'to' => $user->getEmail(),
                'subject' => 'Intranet Québec en réseau : Mot de passe oublier',
                'body' => $message
            ]);
        
    }

    public function onUpdatePassword(ForgotPasswordEvent $event)
    {
        $passwordToken = $event->getPasswordToken();
        $user = $passwordToken->getUser();
        $user->setPlainPassword($event->getPassword());
        $this->manager->persist($user);
    }
    
}
```

My service file:

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
    app.security.login_form_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
        autowire: true

    app.doctrine.hash_password_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Doctrine\HashPasswordListener
        autowire: true
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber }

    app.locale_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
        arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%','@security.authorization_checker']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

    app.login_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
        arguments: ['@session']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onInteractiveLogin }

    app.mailer:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Mailer
        arguments: ['@mailer','@templating']

    app.utility:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Utility
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.filemanager:
        class: AppBundle\Service\FileManager

    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        arguments: ['@translator.default','@request_stack']
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }       
    app.sae:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Sae
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.document:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Document
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.professional:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Professional
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.article:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Article
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.course:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\Course
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']

    app.useraddon:
        class: AppBundle\Service\Entity\UserAddon
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager']
        
    app.jwt_token_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\JwtAuthenticator
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder']
        
    app.listener.forgot_password:
        class: AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener      
        arguments:
            - "@templating"
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
            - { name: templating.helper, alias: templating, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.update_password, method: onUpdatePassword }

    app.ResettingController:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\ResettingController
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: app.ResettingController }

        
    kernel.event_listener.json_request_transformer:
        class: Qandidate\Common\Symfony\HttpKernel\EventListener\JsonRequestTransformerListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: 100 }
```

And this is the controller i based my code on

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\AppBundle;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\ImportForm;
use AppBundle\Form\UserRegistrationForm;
use AppBundle\Form\UserEditForm;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/users", name="app-users-index")
     */
    public function userListAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\User')
            ->findAll();
        $title = $this->get('translator')->trans('Users');
        return $this->render('Users/index.html.twig', [
            'title' => $title,
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/users/add", name="app-users-add")
     */
    public function userAddAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $usergroup = $user->getUsergroup();
        $users = $this->get('app.utility')->getUsersByUsergroupId($usergroup->getId());
        if ($request->get('insert')) {
            $creator = $user;
            $password = $this->get('app.utility')->randomPassword();
            $user = new User();
            $user->setPlainPassword( $password );
            $user->setUsergroup( $creator->getUsergroup() );
            // user
            $user->setShowpro( ($request->get('showpro')) ? $request->get('showpro') : 0 );
            $user->setName( $request->get('name') );
            $user->setTitreid( $request->get('titreid') );
            $user->setExpertise( $request->get('expertise') );
            $user->setNotes( $request->get('notes') );
            $user->setSaeid( $request->get('sae') );
            $user->setEmail( $request->get('email') );
            $user->setPhone( $request->get('phone') );
            $user->setExtension( $request->get('extension') );
            $user->setFax( $request->get('fax') );
            $user->setAddress( $request->get('address') );
            $user->setCity( $request->get('city') );
            $user->setZipcode( $request->get('zipcode') );
            $user->setProvince( 'QC' );
            $user->setCountry( 'CA' );
            $user->setLocale( 'fr' );
            $user->setLanguage( 'fr' );
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            // user addons
            // create and associate tags
            $tags = $request->get('tags');
            $tagsToAssociate = [];
            $i = 0;
            if($tags)
            {
                foreach($tags as $tag)
                {
                    $checkTag = $this->get('app.professional')->getTagById($tag);
                    if( ! $checkTag )
                    {
                        $tag = $this->get('app.professional')->addTagByName($tag);
                    }
                    $tagsToAssociate[$i] = $tag;
                    $i++;
                }
                $this->get('app.useraddon')->associateUserTags( $user->getId(), $tagsToAssociate );
            }
            $secteurs = $request->get('secteurs');
            if($secteurs)
            {
                $this->get('app.useraddon')->associateUserSecteurs( $user->getId(), $secteurs );
            }
            $message = $this->renderView(
                '_Emails/new-account.html.twig',
                [
                    'name' => $user->getName(),
                    'creator' => $creator->getName(),
                    'group' => $creator->getUsergroup()->getName(),
                    'username' => $user->getEmail(),
                    'password' => $password
                ]
            );
            $this->get('app.mailer')->send([
                'from' => 'noreply@quebecenreseau.ca',
                'to' => $user->getEmail(),
                'subject' => 'Intranet Québec en réseau : Nouveau compte',
                'body' => $message
            ]);
            $this->addFlash('success', $user->getEmail() . ' ' . $this->get('translator')->trans('have been added successfully'));
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app-users-index'));
        }
        $title = $this->get('translator')->trans('Users › Add');
        $user = array(
            'id' => '',
            'saeid' => '',
            'showpro' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'titreid' => '',
            'expertise' => '',
            'notes' => '',
            'sae' => '',
            'email' => '',
            'phone' => '',
            'extension' => '',
            'fax' => '',
            'address' => '',
            'city' => '',
            'zipcode' => ''
        );
        $userAddon = array(
            'tags' => '',
            'secteurs' => ''
        );
        $categories = $this->get('app.professional')->getAllCategories();
        $tags = $this->get('app.professional')->getAllTags();
        $saes = $this->get('app.sae')->getAllSaes();
        $titres = $this->get('app.professional')->getAllTitres();
        $secteurs = $this->get('app.professional')->getAllSecteurs();
        return $this->render('Users/show.html.twig', [
            'title' => $title,
            'user' => $user,
            'user_addon'  => $userAddon,
            'categories' => $categories,
            'tags' => $tags,
            'saes' => $saes,
            'titres' => $titres,
            'secteurs' => $secteurs,
            'users' => $users
        ]);
    }
}
```

It uses renderView which I never got working but render did the trick and now the get-> part that does not seem to work. I extended the controller the same way and did not find anything in the service file that would suggest I need to do something else.

Comment: Do you need to inject the Service Container into the EventListener (as explained in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472533/2915099) and then use that `$container` variable to get the object? Also I don't think `ForgotPasswordEventListener`  needs to extend the Controller class

Comment: Can you identify the line that is causing the error? Looking at your controller I only see a `get()` call here: `$this->get('app.mailer')` but the error message doesn't make sense in this context since `$this` would not be `null` here.

Comment: Thats exacly where the error occurs. I added a picture in the question.

Comment: there only are `$this->get` and `$request->get`. use `xdebug` instead of guessing. see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/incompat_ctx

Comment: The only thing i see diffrent is that i use namespace AppBundle\Event; could it be related? As for xdebug, i can't run in dev envirement... I have an open question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948241/symfony-apache-configuration-when-app-dev-is-in-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I played arround and read a lot and never understood why `get->` is not working in my controller. But I've managed to go arround it like so.

```
class ForgotPasswordEventListener
{

private $templating;
private $manager;
protected $mailer;

public function __construct($templating, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $manager, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->templating = $templating;
    $this->manager=$manager;
    $this->mailer=$mailer;
}

/**
 * @param ForgotPasswordEvent $event
 */
public function onCreateToken(ForgotPasswordEvent $event)
{
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Intranet Québec en réseau : Mot de passe oublier'))
            ->setFrom('noreply@quebecenreseau.ca')
            ->setTo($user->getEmail())
            ->setBody(
                $this->templating->render(
                    // templates/emails/registration.html.twig
                    '_Emails/change-password.html.twig',
                    array(
                        'name' => $user->getName(),
                        'tokenLink' => "https://www.quebecenreseau.ca/intranet/password-change/".$user->getId()."/".$passwordToken->getToken()
                    )
                ),
                'text/html'
            );
        if (0 === $this->mailer->send($message)){
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to send email');
        }else{
            echo "done";
        }   
[...]
```

As for my service I did this:

```
app.listener.forgot_password:
    class: AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener      
    arguments:
        - "@templating"
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        - "@mailer"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
        - { name: templating.helper, alias: templating, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.update_password, method: onUpdatePassword }
```

I wish I could of understood why but this will do for now. Hope this helps sombody else in the future!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call the method get() of ContainerInterface. 
To be able to use this method, add ContainerInterface as a part of your service dependencies. So, you can use this attributes to call the get() function

for example:

```
$this->container->get('app.mailer')
```